# Google IME for Japanese Ubuntu 18.04 (Budgie)

Tags: 18.04, input-language, language-support, japanese, ubuntu-budgie

Hello I got Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 and I wanna have Japnese keyboard input. So is there a way to install Google IME on ubuntu?

Comment: Don't think so. I'd suggest that you install `ibus-mozc`, relogin, and then use `ibus-setup` to enable the Mozc input method.

Comment: I haven't heard of Google IME for Ubuntu.  Perhaps you can try the steps given [here](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2017/08/20/japanese-input-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus/).  They are for 16.04, but I don't think something like this would have changed much.

Answer (score 1):

You need go to system settings, language input and add the Japanese language.　Logoff and then login again.  Now, add the "Japanese (Mozc) (Ibus)" input method.

See the details at: https://moritzmolch.com/2287